# How do I store multipule class objects in the same array in Java?

Tags: java

If I create an Array in the class DefaultItems:

```
DefaultItems[] items = new DefaultItems[20];
```

I want to use this as a storage array for 5 different class objects.   I want to store a Car object, Person object and Pet object.

```
 DefaultItems[1] = Car Object;
 DefaultItems[2] = Person Object;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are they subclasses of DefaultItms?

Comment: Sounds like a terrible design.  Why would a Car, Person, and Pet object be encapsulated into an array?  This is a miscarriage of object-oriented design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Car` and `Person` derive from `DefaultItems` then your code should work (assuming the typos are fixed).

If the classes are not related in any way then you can achieve what you want by using `Object[]` instead of `DefaultItems[]`. All classes derive from `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your 5 objects i.e. `Car`, `Person` etc. **are extended from base class `DefaultItems`.** Once you do that, you can achieve what you want.

i.e.

```
 public class Person extends DefaultItems {
   //...
 }

 public class Car extends DefaultItems {
   //...
 }
```

then

```
 DefaultItems[] items = new DefaultItems[2];
 DefaultItems[0] = new Person();
 DefaultItems[1] = new Car();
```

One example with `Number` class and its sub classes as is as below:

```
    Number[] nums = new Number[3];
    nums[0] = new Integer(0);
    nums[1] = new Double(1.0);
    nums[2] = new Float(0.5);

    for(Number num: nums){
        System.out.println(num);//<--prints the numbers
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, in a type safe way, just if all the obejcts you want to store in the array share a common parent class from which they inherit:

```
class Car extends MyObject {
  ...
}

class Person extends MyObject {
  ...
}

MyObject[] array = new MyObject[2];
array[0] = new Car();
array[1] = new Person();
```

But after having added them to the array they can be accessed just as MyObject instances (unless you typecast them, which must be avoided), so if MyObject class doesn't provide a common interface then this is pretty pointless. It's better to use composition:

```
class MyClass {
  Person person;
  Car car;
  ..
}
```